# How to set url alias as article title?

Tags: 7

I'm getting url alias for all articles like mysite.com/node/14 but I wanted to set the url as aritcle titles like this: mysite.com/article-title

So, How to set all url alias as per the articles title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module.

> The Pathauto module automatically generates URL/path aliases for various kinds of content 
> (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without requiring the user to manually specify the path alias. 
> This allows you to have URL aliases like /category/my-node-title instead of /node/123.
>  The aliases are based upon a "pattern" system that uses tokens which the administrator can 
> change.

Comment: what should I type in path pattern?

Comment: I tried [current-page:title] but nothing change..

Comment: @wolverine -  we posted same answers, same time :) but I'm bit late. So I'm going to delete my answer

Comment: @NavinRauniyar use [node:title]

Comment: @KrishnaMohan next time I will wait for some time before posting answer

Comment: @wolverine lol, Oh no!! I didn't mean that! Please don't misunderstand. I was trying to say about the coincidence :)

Comment: @KrishnaMohan no, I didn't misunderstand you, I am just saying by waiting we can avoid similar scenarios. :)

Comment: @NavinRauniyar It will work only for newly created node. For existing node you have to manually add the alias.

Comment: no, it worked for me. I used bulk generate option.